# Getting the value on formula NOW() in Apex

Tags: apex, process-builder, datetime

I have a Process Builder where a field type Double is populated with the following value.

`NOW() - [Case].CreatedDate`

When this action is triggered after around 1 min of creating the Case the value of this calculation is stored as `0.0015`.

I am trying to write the same logic in Apex but non of the following is allowed.

```
Double d = System.now() - case.CreatedDate;
Double d = DateTime.now() - case.CreatedDate;
```

And the following gives results in milliseconds which is a big number.

```
Double d = DateTime.now().getTime() - case.CreatedDate.getTime();
```

How can I get the same logic in Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert milliseconds to days, you simply have to do the correct division.

```
Double milliseconds = Datetime.now().getTime() - record.CreatedDate.getTime();
Double days = milliseconds / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```